# Heroku-toolbelt installation error: sh: 1: Usage:: not found sh: 4: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, installation, ubuntu-12.04, heroku-toolbelt

I've been trying to install Heroku-toolbelt on my ubuntu, but I keep getting the following error:

```
    $ bundle exec wget -q0- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
    sh: 1: Usage:: not found
    sh: 4: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
```

Update: The problem was I hadn't created a Heroku account. I created one and the command worked perfectly.

Comment: try to use 'bash' instead of 'sh' in the pipe.

Comment: @TeTeT I tried bash but got a different error, I posted it above.

Comment: Try downloading the script and run it with 'sh -x <scriptname>' to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'O'(the alphabet) instead of '0'(zero) in -qO-. That should solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "O" instead of "0" solved for me.

Thanks!